# Why is my motion activated light switch in my pantry also controlling my bathroom light?

Tags: electrical

I installed [this motion activated light switch](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LEZKFIW), and felt so smart doing so and getting it to work.  Now I've realized that the motion activator is also controlling the adjacent bathroom light.  Can you point me in the right direction to troubleshoot?  This switch does have a white/neutral wire which I connected.

Comment: Can you please list all the wires that were in the box, their colors, grouping, and how you connected them. Also explaining how they were previously connected would be helpful.

Comment: @jah If the question is not valid anymore, that I guess You can rollback/delete (idk) it.